# How to pass the reference of a random element of a 2d array to a function in c?

Tags: arrays, c

Suppose I have an array `arr[6][6]`. I have a function suppose `int CalculateSum()`. As the argument of the function I do not want to pass the whole array but I want to pass `arr[2][3]` to `CalculateSum`. How can I do that?

Comment: Do not tag C++ for C questions. If there is some C++ aspect in your question, edit the question to explain that.

Comment: Is `CalculateSum` going to operate on multiple array elements starting at `arr[2][3]`, or is it going to work on just the one element? If it is going to operate on multiple elements, which ones will it work on? If it is going to operate on just one, is it going to change it or does it just need the value?

Comment: In C you do not pass the whole array only the reference to it.

Comment: So... `CalculateSum(arr[2][3]);` (which passes the value of the element at position 2;3 of the array) or `CalculateSum(&arr[2][3]);` (which passes the address/reference) is not the answer? Why? Please explain in the question. Also, if you could add as much code as you can, ideally a [mre] of what you have, that would make people happy. And happy users are helpfully mooded users.... ;-)

Comment: I want to operate on multiple elements. I shall iterate from arr[2][3].@EricPostpischil

Comment: what is the type of `arr`? is it `int[6][6]`? or something different?

Answer (score 2):

In C you do not pass the whole array only the reference to it.

If you want to pass the reference to the particular element of the array use `&array[col][row]`.

Example:

```
int foo(int *val)
{
    return *val * *val;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[5][5] = {{1,2,3,4,5},{12,22,32,42,52},{13,23,33,43,53},{14,24,34,44,54},{15,25,35,45,55}};

    printf("%d\n", foo(&a[3][2]));
}
```

### EDIT:

Now probably I understand that OP wants sum of the elements of the square subarray:

```
//sq - size of the square subarray
long long sumSubArray(size_t rows, size_t cols, 
                      size_t rowstart, size_t colstart, 
                      size_t sq, int (*matrixIn)[cols]) 
{
    long long sum = 0;
    for(size_t row = 0; row < sq; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < sq; col++)
        {
            sum += matrixIn[rowstart + row][colstart + col];
        }                
    }
}
```

You need to add some checks if the indexes will not go outside the array.

Comment: int calculateSum(int *curr_location){
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            sum+=* (*(curr_location+i)+j);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}  Actually my problem is with sum+=* (*(curr_location+i)+j); this line. I have passed the address of current location. Now I want to iterate next 3*3 elements of the array.

Comment: @Nakib never do it `((curr_location+i)+j);`

Comment: @Nakib Pass the reference to the array and other parameters. Your way of doing it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The address of `arr[2][3]` is simply `&arr[2][3]`. You can pass this address to `CalculateSum`.

For example, if `arr` is defined as `float arr[6][6]`, `CalculateSum` can be declared with `int CalculateSum(float *p)`. Then, when called with `CalculateSum(&arr[2][3])`, the routine can use `*p` or `p[0]` to access `arr[2][3]`. It can also use `p[1]` and `p[2]` to access `arr[2][4]` and `arr[2][5]`.

Going beyond the current row is not formally defined by the C standard. If `CalculateSum` wants to access `arr[3][3]`, the memory address for this is nominally `p+6`, since the rows of `arr` are six elements long. The C standard does not define using this to access `arr[3][3]`, but compilers support it. (Apple Clang does support accessing multi-dimensional arrays in this way.)

Depending on circumstances, you may need to pass `CalculateSum` arguments telling it how `arr` is laid out in memory (notably whether its rows are six elements long or some other length) and how many elements it is supposed to operate on in each dimension.